Alternative exterior sheathing to 16"x48" rock lath
Property is in Zone 5, mid-Michigan.
House was built in the 1950's. Interior is 1/2" rock lath with a 1" plaster assembly, insulated with cellulose.
2x4 walls 16" oc,
Exterior is sheathed with black paper-faced 1/2" thick rock lath, 16"x48" panels.
1x6 vertical wood siding clads the exterior.
There is no tape, flashing, weather barrier. Nada.
Roof overhangs about 2-3ft adding an element of water deflection
The rock lath is nailed directly to the studs and the wood siding is raw dogging the rock lath.
Seems the siding was caulked at each T&G as it was installed, and nailed into place through the groove as a "blind fastener" with face nails at the top and bottom going into the respective plates, the sill and the rim.
Siding goes right up to the window/door casing, again it's raw dogged without any real measure to keep water out.
Surprisingly, this has stood well for a very long time with very minimal wood/moisture rot, the bottoms of the boards are weathered, but the lath is rock solid. (Pun intended)
My thought was to rebuild it the same way it was originally constructed, given my relative lack of experience in siding. (I know water is bad, and I've done some windows, ext doors, and vinyl siding with good results)
But I'm wary of a few things:

I cannot find any 1/2" rock lath, I understand it may have been discontinued. I also understand many folks substitute drywall when repairing older homes with rock lath, but im unsure if that principal will hold true for using drywall as an exterior sheathing application. Is it moisture resistant enough? Will it have the strength to hold the 1x6 siding?

I also understand I could use plywood sheathing, but the thermal and acoustic properties of this wall are insane, I'd like to maintain those properties as much as possible.

I'm not sure how the inspector would feel about me repairing it the same way it was initially built. I know code calls for weather barrier in zone 5, but none of this wall, (or the rest of the house, have it.) So it feels kinda pointless to try and use it on just this repair area.

Ultimately the code man wants what he wants I'm just not exactly sure what to expect/how to keep him happy in this situation (without ripping down the entire exterior, which I REALLY don't want to do.

There is an exterior type drywall(surprised me also).

@crip659 Do you know of any passages in the IRC that would excuse me repairing things in the same manner as they existed when built?

Your local inspector is the best one.  If it is not a danger to health or or being fire prone, then maybe.  My neighbour had a nice(at a distance) looking brick siding, but it was more like printed tar paper/shingle rolls.  He had to replace all.
